# Find first letter after point in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I need to find the first letter of an account entered in a label. Specifically, I'm interested in being able to find the first letter after the point. For example, if the account entered in the label is "john.smith" I am interested in the code being able to take the "s" Can you help me? (My project is in Visual Basic.)

Comment: Will there *always* be a point and a letter after it?

Comment: How's the question going? If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string, take the second element, take the first char, convert to string

```
Dim letter = input.Split("."c)(1)(0).ToString()
```